# React Redux Thunk with Typescript making api request

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-tsx

I have been trying to make a simple URL request to a third party API. Here is the project I am working on (https://github.com/JMStudiosJoe/ReactPractice/tree/JMStudiosReact). I have been watching Dan Abramov videos, followed this [example from redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) and this [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) and seem to be missing something small since the logs show that my data from the API was recieved and dispatched to the reducer but the state for some reason does not get sent back to the component. 
Below is a summary of code:

//app.tsx:  get the store and use Provider from react-redux

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import store from './redux/store/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { getAddressData } from './redux/actions/voteSmartActions'
import {UIRouter, UIView, UISref, UISrefActive, pushStateLocationPlugin} from 'ui-router-react';
import NavigationBarComponent from './components/navigationBarComponent'

store.dispatch(getAddressData(''))

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationBarComponent userType='buyer' />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The component in question gets loaded from the projectsComponent.tsx file

```js
if(projectName == 'Vote Smart Locally' ) {
        return (
            <VoteSmartLocallyComponent />
        )
}
```

//voteSmartLocallyComponent.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getAddressData } from '../../redux/actions/voteSmartActions'
import store from "../../redux/store/store"
interface VoteSmartState {
    address: string
    userAddressData?: any
}
interface VoteSmartProps {
    fetchAddressData: any 
}
const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCWhwRupMs7IeE4IrGEgHtT0Nt-IGZnP9E'
const endURL = '&key='+ API_KEY
const baseRepURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address='
const baseElectionsURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/elections?alt=json&prettyPrint=true'
class VoteSmartLocallyComponent extends React.Component<VoteSmartProps, VoteSmartState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(props)
        this.state = {
            address: '',
            userAddressData: {}
        }
    }
    removeSpacesAddPluses() {
        return this.state.address.split(' ').join('+')      
    }
    lookupAddress(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const address = this.removeSpacesAddPluses()
        const fullRepURL = baseRepURL + address + endURL
        const fullElectionsURL = baseElectionsURL + address + endURL
        this.props.fetchAddressData(fullRepURL)
            /*
        store.subscribe(this.render)
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'LOOKUP_ADDRESS',
            payload: address
        })
             */
    }

    handleAddress(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const address = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            address: address 
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {console.log('log in the render method')}
            {console.log(this.state)}
            vote smart kids
            need to connect the redux and suff to make request
            <input 
                type='text' 
                placeholder='Address'
                onChange={ e => this.handleAddress(e) }
            />
            <button
                onClick={ e => this.lookupAddress(e) }
            >
            Submit for info
            </button>
        </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        address: '',
        userAddressData: {}
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchAddressData: (url) => dispatch(getAddressData(url))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(VoteSmartLocallyComponent)
```

I am able to call `this.props.fetchAddressData(fullRepURL)` which calls my action

//voteSmartActions.tsx

```js
import {Action} from 'redux'
import store from '../store/store'
import axios from 'axios'

interface VoteSmartAction<Action> {
    type: string
    payload?: any
}
const getAddressData = (fullURL: string) => {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        if (fullURL !== '') { 
            return axios.get(fullURL).then(function (response) {
                dispatch(addressDataSuccess(response))
            
            }).catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error)
            })
        }
    }
}
const addressDataSuccess = (addressData: any) => {
    return {
        type: 'HANDLE_RETURN_DATA',
        payload: addressData,
        addressData
    }
}
export {
    getAddressData, VoteSmartAction
}
```

And from there goes to my reducer

//voteSmartReducer.tsx

```js
import {Action} from 'redux'
import {VoteSmartAction, getAddressData} from '../actions/voteSmartActions'
import axios from 'axios'
const INITIAL_STATE: any = {
    address: '',
    userAddressData: {}
}
const VoteSmartReducer = (state: any = INITIAL_STATE, action: VoteSmartAction<Action>): any => {
    switch(action.type) {

        case "HANDLE_RETURN_DATA":
            console.log("in reducer handling return payload is")
            const returnData = {
                ...state,
                userAddressData: action.payload 
            }
            console.log(returnData)
            
            return returnData

        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default VoteSmartReducer
```

From there the state I made in the reducer should be returned back to the component with the data I fetched but it isn't. I would appreciate any advice or help, thanks.

Comment: was also following this post and it is closely related to my code as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794895/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-in-react-redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're passing in an empty object for `userAddressData` and empty string for `address` in mapStateToProps. So your component will always have these values.

You need specify within mapStateToProps, where the data lies within the state tree.

Look at the shape of your reducer, and see where where the data sits within the state tree, and then map it in the following way within mapStateToProps.

**Example**

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import voteSmartReducer from './VoteSmartReducer' // assuming this is in same directory
import someOtherReducer from './someOtherReducer' // example purposes

export default combineReducers({
    userAddressData: voteSmartReducer,
    otherExample: someOtherReducer
})
```

As you can see, the data returned by the voteSmartReducer is mapped to the key userAddressData in combineReducers. So `state.userAddressData` points to this. This is how you would map the state to props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userAddressData: state.userAddressData,
        otherExample: state.otherExample
    }
}
```

When you create the store, you import the reducer from index.js and pass it in as the first argument to `createStore`.

Example.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from './index.js'

const store = createStore(
        reducers
)
```

Comment: Thank you @meteorBuzz this all makes more sense now and connecting the reducer to the component to continue the flow of data from the state tree. I do not know to mark this correct or not since now I CAN see the data I want in the mapStateToProps function and be returning it properly but for some reason, the log in the render method for printing the state is still the old state and not the new one. Is that a new issue though?

Comment: Yes I think I found it now and how to get the data I need to the state through the props, the hint was the function name mapStateToProps and then I checked inside of this.props at the render() method and booom there was my data THANK YOU @meteorBuzz